# Are Firestore updates charged the same cost as writes?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-firestore

According to [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data), it is possible to update a single field without updating the entire document:

```
def update_create_if_missing():
db = firestore.Client()
city_ref = db.collection(u'cities').document(u'BJ')

city_ref.update({
    u'capital': True
}, firestore.CreateIfMissingOption(True))
```

**Are Firestore updates charged as writes?**

Is there an option such as "update if different" instead of the current one which is updating if missing?

I have built quite a heavy price comparison application with more than 1 million products (each product is a document in Firestore) updated on a daily basis. It would be quite expensive if I had to pay 1.000.000 writes per day on top of the Firestore reads.

Is there any alternative I could explore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firestore document updates are not different than writes.  Any operation that changes a document is considered a write.

Comment: Does overwriting identical data on a document count as another write? Since Firestore doesn't have to update its index.

Comment: @SlickSlime If your question isn't addressed in the existing documentation about pricing, you should reach out to Firebase support with questions about billing. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Answer (score 1):

To add to Doug's answer, Firestore considers document creations, updates and even deletes as billable write events. Read up more on their official documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events).